# JComboBox check that a Select isnt from the program

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have the following Programm

```
package utests;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Foo extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox combo;

    public static void main(String... args) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.showUI();
    }

    public void showUI() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    this.setContentPane(pane);
    combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            System.out.println("You selected " + combo.getSelectedItem());
        }
        }
    });
    refreshBox();

    pane.add(combo);
    this.pack();
    }

    public void refreshBox(){
    combo.removeAllItems();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("godsf");
    list.add("södlkf");
    list.add("ldsjlkfdsj");

    for (String s : list) {
        combo.addItem(s);
    }
    }
}
```

The programm will immediatly show you the string

```
You selected godsf
```

How can i check if the user checked something and not the program?

edit: i changed the programm a bit: The problem is that i need to refresh the box some times. Every Time i refresh the data in the box, the ItemListener is hit, and i get wrong results.
How can i check that a Action is done by the User and not by the Programm itself? To add some booleans seems to be not very Java-like...

Comment: What you exactly want to do? Can you please elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code of method refreshBox to code below:

```
public void refreshBox()
{
    combo.removeAllItems();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("godsf");
    list.add("södlkf");
    list.add("ldsjlkfdsj");

    for (String s : list) 
    {
        combo.insertItemAt(s, 0);
    }
}
```

does it meet your requirement?
I just change the code:

```
combo.addItem(s);
```

to the code:

```
combo.insertItemAt(s, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to know that user has selected an option or not without writing a single line of code.
But if u want to know that whether user has selected an option or your program have selected it then i think u will have to write ur own custom logic for that.

here is the code which will print the selected option only when user have selected it.

```
package utests;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Foo extends JFrame {
private JComboBox combo;

public static void main(String... args) {
Foo f = new Foo();
f.showUI();
}

public void showUI() {
this.setVisible(true);
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
this.setContentPane(pane);
combo = new JComboBox();
refreshBox();

pane.add(combo);
combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        System.out.println("You selected " + combo.getSelectedItem());
    }
    }
});
this.pack();
}

public void refreshBox(){
combo.removeAllItems();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("godsf");
list.add("södlkf");
list.add("ldsjlkfdsj");

for (String s : list) {
    combo.addItem(s);
}
}
}
```

here we have added the ItemListener to combo box when it is already shown to user. So it will print the selected value only when user have selected it

Comment: same problem here: What if i need to refresh it very often? then i have to remove the Listener all the time and re-add it...

Comment: @reox Why you want to refresh it frequently? are you monitoring some data and adding that to your comboBox?

Comment: i mentioned that if u want to do so then u will have to write your custom logic...

Answer (score -1):

```
package utests;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Foo extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.showUI();
    }
    bool first = false;
    public void showUI()
    {
        this.setVisible(true);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        this.setContentPane(pane);
        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0)
            {
                if(first)
                if(arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    System.out.println("You selected " + combo.getSelectedItem());

                }
                //from now on we'll see the selections
                first = true;

            }
        });
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("godsf");
        list.add("södlkf");
        list.add("ldsjlkfdsj");
        for(String s : list)
        {
            combo.addItem(s);
        }
        pane.add(combo);
        this.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: okay but what if i need to change the data inside the programm several times (and yes i do :))? then i need to set the boolean new all the time... Is this the best solution?

Comment: you have to mark the program actions somehow so this might be a solution.

Comment: What's this? Meaning less answer to a meaningless question.

Comment: you can make a function to do this